# control a robot with pymorse on MORSE simulator question

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, control

I am new to Morse and robotics.

This code control the robot by giving the linear and angular velocity.

This is the scene description

```
from morse.builder import *
robot = ATRV()
motion = MotionVW()
motion.add_stream('socket')
robot.append(motion)

semanticL = SemanticCamera()
semanticL.translate(x=0.2, y=0.3, z=0.9)
robot.append(semanticL)

semanticR = SemanticCamera()
semanticR.translate(x=0.2, y=-0.3, z=0.9)
robot.append(semanticR)

motion.add_stream('socket')
semanticL.add_stream('socket')
semanticR.add_stream('socket')

env = Environment('land-1/trees')
env.set_camera_location([10.0, -10.0, 10.0])
env.set_camera_rotation([1.0470, 0, 0.7854])
```

and this is the control script

```
import pymorse
with pymorse.Morse() as simu:
    simu.robot.motion.publish({"v": 3, "w": -1})
```

The robot moves well. But when I remove the semantic cameras from the scene description the robot do not move. I am confused, they are just sensor, why the robot don't move ?

Comment: I reposted the question on https://github.com/morse-simulator/morse/issues/567

Comment: What is the behavior you are expecting?

Comment: move from point x to y by changing linear and angular velocity